# How to get a collection of elements with Nightwatch .elemets()

Tags: testing, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I'm testing a website with Nightwatch and trying to get a collection of elements using the `.elements()` method.

I have the following code:

```
client.elements('css selector', 'p[class="f5 color-fg-muted mb-0 mt-1"]', function(elements) {
        console.log(elements.value);
        elements.value.forEach(item => {
          console.log(item.ELEMENT);
        });
      });
```

The output is:

```
...
{
    'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'DE70929C2F5311AC55FD8AFEE548EA6D_element_178'
  },
  {
    'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'DE70929C2F5311AC55FD8AFEE548EA6D_element_179'
  },
  {
    'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'DE70929C2F5311AC55FD8AFEE548EA6D_element_180'
  },
  ... 80 more items
]
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
...
```

Mentioned selector points to a couple of `p` elements and all I want is to get the text from them.
([p elements on a page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZrHs.png))

What should I do to get exactly `p` (not "element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf") elements and then the text of them?

Answer (score 0):

After the `forEach` I believe you get the [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) object. Try accessing it directly.

```js
client.elements('css selector', 'p[class="f5 color-fg-muted mb-0 mt-1"]', function(elements) {
  console.log(elements.value);
  elements.value.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.innerText);
  });
});
```